# Variance of sum of weighted gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, variance

This problem comes from [section 3.2. at page 7 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04034.pdf)
Suppose there are $N$ independent gaussian random variables $z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_N$. That is
$$z_i \sim N(\mu _i,\sigma _i^2).$$
Now let
$$z=\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_iz_i,S=\sum_{i=1}^N w_i.$$
My question is how to show
\begin{align}
Var(z)&=\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2(\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2)-{\bar z}^2, \\
\bar z &= \frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i\mu_i.
\end{align}
To my understanding, $Var(z)=\bar {z^2}- {\bar z}^2$. But I am stuck on deriving $\bar {z^2}=\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i^2(\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2)$, can anyone help out?

**Update**
 I guess that I abstracted the problem in an erroneous way. In effect, it is an instance of [gaussian mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model), so the probability density function is as follows:
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i \cdot N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$$
where $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2*\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{(z-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2})$, according to the definition of 2nd moment:
$$\bar {z^2} = \mathbb E_f(z^2)=\int z^2f(z)dz= \frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_i(\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2).$$
This [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/what-is-the-variance-of-the-weighted-mixture-of-two-gaussians?answertab=active#tab-top) formulated a similar problem in a more canonical way.

Comment: I corrected your mistake .. should be $w_i^2$ instead of $w_i$

Comment: Rather than directly manipulating formulas related to Gaussians, I think you would find your arguments to be cleaner if you used general facts such as (a) the variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances, (b) $\mathrm{Var}(cX) = c^2 \mathrm{Var}(X)$, and (c) the expectation of the product of independent random variables is the product of their expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E(z) = \frac{1}{S} w_i E(z_i) =  \frac{1}{S} w_i \mu_i =  \bar z$$
$$\text{Var}(z) = E(z^2) - \bar z^2 \tag{1}$$
where 
$$E(z^2) = \Big(\frac{1}{S}\sum_{i=1}^N w_iz_i \Big)^2 = \frac{1}{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^N w_iw_jE(z_iz_j) $$
Notice that, we have that 
$$E(z_i^2) = (\sigma_i^2 + \mu_i^2) $$
and under the assumption of independent random variables
$$E(z_iz_j) = E(z_i)E(z_j) = \mu_i\mu_j $$
This gives us
$$E(z^2) = \frac{1}{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^N w_i^2 (\sigma_i^2 + \mu_i^2) + \frac{1}{S^2}\sum_{i \neq j} w_iw_j \mu_i\mu_j \tag{2}$$
Replacing $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get
$$\text{Var}(z) = \frac{1}{S^2}\sum_{j=1}^N w_i^2 (\sigma_i^2 + \mu_i^2) + \underbrace{\frac{1}{S^2}\sum_{i \neq j} w_iw_j \mu_i\mu_j}_C- \bar z^2$$
You need the additional assumption of zero mean to say that $C = 0$ and to arrive at your expression.